# Toast notification every 15 seconds

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

How can I show a toast notification every 15 seconds while the application is in background? DispatcherTimer doesn't work because my app is suspended and background tasks can't run at this frequency.

Comment: showing toast every 15 seconds sounds like a bad idea. I any case push notifications is the only way to produce toasts at rate higher then every 15min

Comment: I actually started a similar question, you may check it at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523102/toast-notifications-only-pop-up-if-the-app-is-being-activated/16523954#16523954

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Background Task to do toast notifications, but the minimum interval is 15 minutes.
Michael

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you want your app to show notifications every 15 seconds, you should make a great snapped view for it.  The 15-minute interval has much to do with making a system that has longer battery life.

Comment: Technically, the problem lie in how you can trigger a background task, which can then create a periodic timer that fires every 15 seconds to accomplish your task.  `_periodicTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(new TimerElapsedHandler(PeriodicTimerCallback), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15000));`

Comment: @MichaelS.Scherotter If the user knows and accepts what my application does, I don't think it matters what I am trying to accomplish. In my case, a snapped view would be too much. I think developers should be educated, not limited.