# Toast notifications only pop up if the app is being activated

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have this problem with toast notifications, my app shows toast notifications only when it is activated (I.e: when I am using it).

Here is my code for the toast notifications:

```
    private void ShowToastNotification(string text)
    {
        var xml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText01);

        xml.GetElementsByTagName("text")[0].AppendChild(xml.CreateTextNode(text));

        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(new ToastNotification(xml));
    }
```

My application is simply a reminder application, user set time and text and when it is time the app will show toast notification for that text.
I simply use a looped timer that checks for reminders each 5 seconds.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherTimer d = new DispatcherTimer();
        d.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,5);
        d.Start();
        d.Tick += delegate
        {
            CHECK();
        };
    }

    private void CHECK()
    {
        foreach (REMINDER_CLASS er in REMINDERS)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:tt") == er.DateTime)
            {
                ShowToastNotification(er.Reminder);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

So when time comes it does not show the toast notification and when I click on the application it shows the notification, it is like it was suspended and when I opened it it resumed.

By the way I have Toast capable set to yes in my appxmanifest and also added BackGround Tasks of type: Timer and System Event inside my Declarations.

The solution could be not allowing the app to sleep or suspend but I don't know how to stop the app from suspending.
And the other solution could be BackGround Tasks and I would be thankful if you gave me a good simple resource for background tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making this harder than it needs to be :)  If you used [scheduled notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868224%28v=win.10%29.aspx) it would just work and you wouldn't need any background tasks.

If you do want to work with background tasks, there is the [Introduction to Background Tasks](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27411) whitepaper that may be of help.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the solution indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the details and code you've shared, you should look into the [`ScheduledToastNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br208607.aspx) class. Windows will show scheduled toasts for an app at a specified time, even if the app is not running or is suspended.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the solution indeed!